# jQuery.kinetic. Lose link positions

Tags: jquery

First of all, I'm so sorry for my low english level. I am from Spain, and I'm just starting classes, so it's possible ( I'm sure ) I will make a lot of mistakes. I'm really sorry!

Ok, I am using jQuery.kinetic plugin for scroll a big image. All are working fine. But, I see a great problem.. I have some "links" and "divs" that are situated on the image. The problem is, when scrolling the image, this "links" and "divs", obviously, keep the position. So, the details of the image change her position, but not the links. Keeping the original position. This is a problem because links make reference to details from the image. Therefore links, divs and the image are not synchronized.

Somebody knows the way to obtain the image, and the links ( and divs ) associated to the image, can move synchronously??

Really thank you, I have tried everything and I can't think of anything more..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is so easy! :)

I put the "kinetic scroll" action only for the `<div>` wich containt the image. And then, the links. It's not correct. the correct is to put the action of kinetic for a `<DIV>` wich contains the image and the links!

Thank you!!